# Is it necessary to dual boot Ubuntu and windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, software-installation

I'm new to the Linux OS. And I've choosen Ubuntu as my preferred os for my PC. I want to know. Is it necessary to dual boot windows and Ubuntu. Personally, I'd like to have only Ubuntu installed on my PC as switching between windows and Ubuntu won't be attractive to me.

Comment: Not at all. I haven't used Windows in more than a decade. It's probably easiest for you to boot to a live instance (after backing up your data), nuke all your partitions, make the disk just one partition, and then install a nice fresh copy of your favorite Linux flavor. There's absolutely no need to have any other OS unless you want to.

Comment: I run Windows in a virtual machine for the single program that I need - other than that, Ubuntu is an excellent choice.

Comment: I dual boot my system, I have 2x Ubuntu systems (my current *hirsute* system I nearly always use, and an older *bionic* system that is a fall back).  Single, Dual, or multiple OSes are all up to you  (I've got boxes with 5x systems)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. You can have only Ubuntu installed on your PC. GRUB boot loader used to boot Ubuntu is flexible and allows you to boot one or more operating systems of your choice. You can reformat your HDD or SSD and install Ubuntu only on the whole drive or create 2 or more partitions and install 2 or more different Linux distros. Please make sure to do a complete backup of your files (documents, pictures, videos, music, software, etc.) before formatting the drive, since formatting will erase all files on your drive.